# Load an external image in <img> tag in a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

I want to know that how to load external images in an image tag such as:

```
<div id="page4">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRX1-0FwHVmDbsTFz8454Sx3fZFeQ-kO-xZ-Q6aYzMw3dCh6ybHT8TApuBPnA"/>
</div>
```

What do I have to add to `manifest.json`?

It's giving the following error:

```
Refused to load the image 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRX1-0FwHVmDbsTFz8454Sx3fZFeQ-kO-xZ-Q6aYzMw3dCh6ybHT8TApuBPnA' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Content Security Policy in apps cannot be relaxed.

If you want to mix in external resources in your app (outside of a `<webview>`), you need to [fetch them yourself](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy#remote_resources):

> You can fetch remote resources via XMLHttpRequest and serve them via blob:, data:, or filesystem: URLs (see [Referencing external resources](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external)).

Answer (score 6):

This is such a common problem, the Chrome team have developed a library for you to help with this: [Chrome Packaged Apps Resource Loader](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/apps-resource-loader)

As per the docs:

> You can request external images using XMLHttpRequest and transform
>   them into ObjectURLs. Then set the src attribute in the  tag to
>   each ObjectURL and it should work.
>
> Since this is a very common use case, we created this library to
>   simplify it. Just drop the apps-resource-loader ral.min.js to your
>   project and then:

```
var remoteImage, 
    container = document.querySelector('.imageContainer'),
    toLoad = { 'images': [ 
       'http://myserver.com/image1.png', 
       'http://myserver.com/image2.png' ] }; // list of image URLs

toLoad.images.forEach(function(imageToLoad) {
      remoteImage = new RAL.RemoteImage(imageToLoad);
      container.appendChild(remoteImage.element);
      RAL.Queue.add(remoteImage);
});
RAL.Queue.setMaxConnections(4);
RAL.Queue.start();
```

> Remember that you need permission in the manifest.json to all domains
>   you will be XHR'ing to. If you don't know beforehand where those
>   images will be hosted, you can ask permission for any url:

```
permissions: ['<all_urls>'],
```

> For other usages, please see the simple demo at:
>   https://github.com/GoogleChrome/apps-resource-loader/tree/master/demo